# check text box value is according to a prefix

Tags: javascript, php, textbox

I have text box. 
Users can enter Student Id into that.
Student id is in this format DIP0001.
First three letters should be DIP and the remaining 4 digits should be numeric and can only upto 4 characters.
So how can I check whether entered data is in this format using javascript.
Please help.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a regular expression pattern and test it against that value to see if it matches that exact pattern.
HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="studentId">Student ID</label>
  <input id="studentId" type="text">

  <button id="btn" type="button">Validate</button>

  // Embedded script so that you don't have to load an external file
  <script>
      var input = document.getElementById('studentId');

      var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

      var pattern = /DIP+\d{1,3}/g;

      btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(pattern.test(input.value)) {
          alert('It enter code here`atches!');
        }else {
          alert('It does not match!');
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS FILE:

```
// This pattern looks something like this: DIP0000
var pattern = /DIP+\d{1,3}/g;

// studentId is the ID of the input field that contains the Student ID
var studentIdInput = document.getElementById('studentId');

// Check the pattern against the provided Student ID
if(pattern.test(studentIdInput.value)) {
    alert('It matches the pattern!');
}
```

EDIT 1: I have built the functionality in the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vldzamfirescu/QBNrW/
Hope it helps!

EDIT2: I have updated the JSFiddle to match any other combinations up to 4 digits; check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/vldzamfirescu/QBNrW/1/ Let me know if it solved your problem!

Comment: I have edited my post. Check the EDIT2 section and that particular JSFiddle.

Comment: do i have to load any js file for this.when i try ur code on local, it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to set the ID of your Input field to studentId and load your JS file in the HTML. Then, you can simply copy the code from the JSFiddle (the javascript code). Also, make sure that the button that you have in your HTML file has the id of btn.

Comment: I have updated my post with the content of the HTML file. Also, I've embedded the JavaScript code so that you don't have to import an external file.

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function validate(val) {
            if (val.value != "") {
                var filter = /^[DIP]|[dip]+[\d]{1,4}$/
                if (filter.test(val.value)) { return (true); }
                else { alert("Please enter currect Student Id"); }
                val.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" onblur="return validate(this);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expresions.

If found a valid Student ID, the pattern will return true:

```
function validateStudentId(id) { 
    var re = /DIP[0-9]{4}/;

    return re.test(id);
}
```

// **Edited** for use with a click event:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if( validateStudentId(document.getElementById('textBox').value) ){
          alert('correct');
    }else{
         alert('invalid ID');
    }
});
```

Comment: doesnt even call the function.

Comment: Because you need put a event to call the 'validateStudentId()' function. Try with my edited code.